# How can i open .vhdx using windows 7?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I have Windows 7 running on my machine, and other hand I have virtual hard disk file(.vhdx), which is creates using Windows 8. So as I  know found,

Hyper-V isn't available on Windows 7 client SKUs, like Enterprise. It's only available on Windows Server 2008 x64 (some SKUs), Windows Server 2008 R2 (most SKUs), Windows 8 Professional x64, Windows 8 Enterprise x64, and Windows Server 2012 (again, most SKUs).
You've just installed the management tools which allow you to manage a remote instance of Hyper-V.

Is this correct ? If yes then is there any way i can open this .Vhdx in any other Softwares on Windows7 . Or how can I use it ?

I found below blog on "How to Restore VHD File backup" but looking for alternative way? 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/how-to-restore-vhd-file-backup/f3ed3ca5-3079-40cd-a959-835caeba80a7

Thank you

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming. Try https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 5):

Royally late ... but I had the same problem and ended up implementing it in my software.

To answer your question

> is there any way i can open this .Vhdx in any other Softwares on Windows7

You can use IsoBuster to open the *.vhdx files and extract files from the image file to your Windows 7 PC.  ( download: [www.isobuster.com/](http://www.isobuster.com) )

I hope this helps ?